# Chinese characters in strings for dynamic text in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a Flash file which contains some dynamic text boxes. ActionScript is being used to fill these boxes using strings. However, I can't seem to get Chinese characters to appear properly. I've tried the actual unicode character as well as their unicode-escaped equivalent but when I export the movie, nothing shows up (blank - it was assumed that the characters are not even present). The EURO symbol does show up but not any of my Asian chars. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

e.g.

```
myTitle = "Hello 新浪网"
```

where myTitle is the dynamic text box's variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.

First add your font to the Library.  Right click the Library and choose "Add Fonts".  Select your the font that you want, name it something e.g. "MyFont", Choose the point size to match the size that you're using in your dynamic text box.
Then for your dynamic text box, select "MyFont" as the Font and also choose to Embed Characters.  Select the Chinese character set that you want.

Now try it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the font. Or at least load it before displaying those characters.

Comment: You need to embed the Chinese font. Arial isn't Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Jase21 is right there's an issue with the way your embedding your fonts. You either haven't done it at all or you've done it improperly. Heres a good video tutorial that should help you out:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=102

Comment: Well it sounds like it might not have been done at all. I inherited the code from someone else. I can copy and paste the Chinese characters into static text fields though I'm sure this is unrelated right?

Comment: Try using the TLFTextField object instead of regular TextField. And yes, when you paste into a static text field flash does everything in the background to ensure that font shows up properly for you, so this would be unrelated to what you're trying to do.